# JS How to count seconds to make bot do an operation every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, game-development

I am trying to make a cookie clicker game, and one item that you can get in shop is a bot where it adds `x` amount of credits to your current amount of credits every second. I want to be able to make multiple of these bots with variations, so not sure if setInterval would be usable in this case. How can I make this?
Note: The timer only starts when a variable is turned to false, so the timer shouldn't start when the app is opened.
P.S. I am using React

```
let bought = false
const [credits, setCredits] = useState
if (bought) {
   For every second {
     setCredits(credits+1)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use setInterval to achieve this.

Comment: https://sebhastian.com/setinterval-react/

Comment: i'll try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to calculate seconds after each reaction on click,
you should use `setInterval()` in JavaScript function.

Example --

```
let time = document.getElementById("time");
function clock(){
    let date = new Date();
    let clocktime = (date.toString().split('G')[0]);
    time.innerHTML = `${clocktime}`;
}
setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

First target an element then change its text to this function's output, and give time here in `setInterval()` function, for how many seconds you want to repeat that function (for how many seconds)